# XmlSerializer trying to serialize outside of declared type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization, xmlserializer

I have a class called `Location` which I want to be serialized by the XmlSerializer. I have this working on other classes, but this particular class is throwing an issue that it can't serialize member `SmartApp.Contract.AccessorialCharges.` The `AccessorialCharges` class was generated using Entity Framework v6.x on a database that is provided by a third party.

The crazy part about all of this - `Location` has no direct properties nor navigational properties to the `AccessorialCharges` entity, and there's no connection from that `AccessorialCharges` entity to `Location.`

In my mind, there should be no reason for EF to try to serialize the `AccessorialCharges` entity at all.

Here's the syntax I'm using to do the serialization:

```
var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Location));  
const string filePath = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\";  
using (var writer = new StreamWriter($"{filePath}location.xml"))  
{  
    xml.Serialize(writer, location);  
}
```

The error is raised on the declaration of the XmlSerializer, and the full content of the error message is: `[NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member SmartAppData.Contract.AccessorialCharges of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'1[[SmartAppData.AccessorialCharge, SmartAppData, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.]`

Has anyone seen this unexpected behavior before and been able to come up with a workaround? I looked for ways to "force" EF to use List<> rather than ICollection<>, but that was an unsuccessful search, and not sure that would be a good way to solve the issue as the Interfaces seem to be more efficient when it comes to EF.

Per request, here's the location class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SmartAppData.Entities._3XXXX
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Location
    {

    public EntityHeader EntityHeader { get; set; }

    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeOrganizationName()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(OrganizationName);
    }

    public string TradingPartnerNum { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeTradingPartnerNum()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TradingPartnerNum);
    }

    public string TradingPartnerType { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeTradingPartnerType()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TradingPartnerType);
    }

    public string LocNum { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeLocNum()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(LocNum);
    }

    public string LocationType { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeLocationType()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(LocationType);
    }

    public bool? IsActive { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeIsActive()
    {
        return null != IsActive;
    }

    public bool? IsBillTo { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeIsBillTo()
    {
        return null != IsBillTo;
    }

    public bool? IsRemitTo { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeIsRemitTo()
    {
        return null != IsRemitTo;
    }

    public bool? IsCorporate { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeIsCorporate()
    {
        return null != IsCorporate;
    }

    public string AddrName { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeAddrName()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AddrName);
    }

    public string Addr1 { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeAddr1()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Addr1);
    }

    public string Addr2 { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeAddr2()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Addr2);
    }

    public string Addr3 { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeAddr3()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Addr3);
    }

    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeCityName()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CityName);
    }

    public string StateCode { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeStateCode()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(StateCode);
    }

    public string CountryIso2 { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeCountryIso2()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CountryIso2);
    }

    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializePostalCode()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostalCode);
    }

    public decimal? Latitude { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeLatitude()
    {
        return null != Latitude;
    }

    public decimal? Longitude { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeLongitude()
    {
        return null != Longitude;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set from SmartDataEnums.TimeZoneType
    /// </summary>
    public string TimeZoneType { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeTimeZoneType()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TimeZoneType);
    }

    public string CalendarName { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeCalendarName()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CalendarName);
    }

    public string CalendarAppointmentName { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeCalendarAppointmentName()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CalendarAppointmentName);
    }

    public int? CalendarOffsetDays { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeCalendarOffsetDays()
    {
        return null != CalendarOffsetDays;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set from SmartDataEnums.CommercialResidentialType
    /// </summary>
    public string CommercialResidentialType { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeCommercialResidentialType()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CommercialResidentialType);
    }

    public bool? AllowsHazmat { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeAllowsHazmat()
    {
        return null != AllowsHazmat;
    }

    public string HazmatContact { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeHazmatContact()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HazmatContact);
    }

    public string HazmatPhone { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeHazmatPhone()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HazmatPhone);
    }

    public int? NumPickupDocks { get; set; } = null;

    public int? NumDeliveryDocks { get; set; } = null;

    public bool? IsDeliveryAptRequired { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeIsDeliveryAptRequired()
    {
        return null != IsDeliveryAptRequired;
    }

    public bool? IsPickupAptRequired { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeIsPickupAptRequired()
    {
        return null != IsPickupAptRequired;
    }

    public SmartAppUomTypes.VolumeType VolumeCrossdockPoolMax { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeVolumeCrossdockPoolMax()
    {
        return null != VolumeCrossdockPoolMax;
    }

    public SmartAppUomTypes.VolumeType VolumeCrossdockPoolMin { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeVolumeCrossdockPoolMin()
    {
        return null != VolumeCrossdockPoolMin;
    }

    public SmartAppUomTypes.WeightType WeightCrossdockPoolMax { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeWeightCrossdockPoolMax()
    {
        return null != WeightCrossdockPoolMax;
    }

    public SmartAppUomTypes.WeightType WeightCrossdockPoolMin { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeWeightCrossdockPoolMin()
    {
        return null != WeightCrossdockPoolMin;
    }

    public string CrossdockPoolConstraint { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeCrossdockPoolConstraint()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CrossdockPoolConstraint);
    }

    public bool? DoNotAllowMultistop { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeDoNotAllowMultistop()
    {
        return null != DoNotAllowMultistop;
    }

    public string DefaultLtlDeliveryTime { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeDefaultLtlDeliveryTime()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultLtlDeliveryTime);
    }

    public string DefaultLtlPickupTime { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeDefaultLtlPickupTime()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultLtlPickupTime);
    }

    public string DefaultParcelGroundDelivery { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeDefaultParcelGroundDelivery()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultParcelGroundDelivery);
    }

    public string DefaultParcelPickup { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeDefaultParcelPickup()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultParcelPickup);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set from SmartDataEnums.TradingPartnerType
    /// </summary>
    public string TradingPartnerDivision { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeTradingPartnerDivision()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TradingPartnerDivision);
    }

    public string AltLocNum { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeAltLocNum()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AltLocNum);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set from SmartDataEnums.StopPreferenceType
    /// </summary>
    public string StopPreferencePickup { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeStopPreferencePickup()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(StopPreferencePickup);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set from SmartDataEnums.StopPreferenceType
    /// </summary>
    public string StopPreferenceDelivery { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeStopPreferenceDelivery()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(StopPreferenceDelivery);
    }

    public string RoutingGuideGroup { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeRoutingGuideGroup()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RoutingGuideGroup);
    }

    public bool? IsOnCreditHold { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeIsOnCreditHold()
    {
        return null != IsOnCreditHold;
    }

    public bool? IgnoreCreditLimit { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeIgnoreCreditLimit()
    {
        return null != IgnoreCreditLimit;
    }

    public SmartAppUomTypes.CurrencyType CreditLimit { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeCreditLimit()
    {
        return null != CreditLimit;
    }

    public SmartAppUomTypes.CurrencyType OverAllowance { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeOverAllowance()
    {
        return null != OverAllowance;
    }

    public SmartAppUomTypes.CurrencyType CreditUsed { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeCreditUsed()
    {
        return null != CreditUsed;
    }

    public SmartAppUomTypes.CurrencyType CreditAvailable { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeCreditAvailable()
    {
        return null != CreditAvailable;
    }

    public DateTime? LastCreditUpdateDate { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeLastCreditUpdateDate()
    {
        return null != LastCreditUpdateDate;
    }

    public DateTime? LastPaymentDate { get; set; } = null;
    public bool ShouldSerializeLastPaymentDate()
    {
        return null != LastPaymentDate;
    }

    public string TerminalCode { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeTerminalCode()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TerminalCode);
    }

    public string TerminalProCode { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeTerminalProCode()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TerminalProCode);
    }

    [XmlArray("LocContacts")]
    [XmlArrayItem("LocContact")]
    public List<LocContact> LocContacts { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeLocContacts()
    {
        return null != LocContacts;
    }

    [XmlArray("LocComments")]
    [XmlArrayItem("LocComment")]
    public List<Comment> LocComments { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeLocComments()
    {
        return null != LocComments;
    }

    [XmlArray("LocRefNums")]
    [XmlArrayItem("LocRefNum")]
    public List<RefNum> LocRefNums { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeLocRefNums()
    {
        return null != LocRefNums;
    }

    [XmlArray("LocRelatedPartys")]
    [XmlArrayItem("LocRelatedParty")]
    public List<LocRelatedParty> LocRelatedPartys { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeLocRelatedPartys()
    {
        return null != LocRelatedPartys;
    }

    [XmlArray("LocActivitys")]
    [XmlArrayItem("LocActivity")]
    public List<LocActivity> LocActivitys { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeLocActivitys()
    {
        return null != LocActivitys;
    }
    }
}

using System;

namespace SmartAppData.Entities._3XXXX
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class EntityHeader
    {
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; } = null;
        public bool ShouldSerializeDateCreated()
        {
            return null != DateCreated;
        }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeCreatedBy()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CreatedBy);
        }

        public DateTime? DateLastModified { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeDateLastModified()
        {
            return null != DateLastModified;
        }

        public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeLastModifiedBy()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastModifiedBy);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your Location class code.

Comment: @JamesDev I just added the Location.cs code...it's 395 lines long which is why I hesitated to post it in the first go-round.

Comment: What is in EntityHeader class?

Comment: @JamesDev Very little is in the EntityHeader, but it's been included at the base of the Location code.

Comment: And LocContact, Comment, RefNum, LocRelatedParty, LocActivity are simple property classes?

Comment: @JamesDev Also, I've gone through the LocContact, Comment, RefNum, LocRelatedParty and LocActivity classes, and none of them have anything to do with AccessorialCharges, either. They're basic 10-line descriptive classes that hold items like contact names, activity performed, related party (refers to contact), etc...but still nothing that touches AccessorialCharges...or anything else in the EF generated classes, for that matter.

Comment: What is in the location variable

Comment: @JamesDev the location variable is an object of type `Location` passed in from the code.

Comment: 1) Without a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I don't think we're going to be able to help much.  Your current code doesn't compile due to missing class definitions; can you make complete example of the problem?  Possibly by removing properties until you find the one(s) that are causing the problem?  2) Can you include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message and traceback?  That might help somewhat in the absence of a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Location));
const string filePath = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\";
using (TextWriter writeStream = new StreamWriter($"{filePath}location.xml");{  
    xml.Serialize(writeStream , location);
}
```

Comment: @SPetrosov - The Serializer fails on the first `var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Location));` line. It never makes it to the `using` statement.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the [Serializable()] class annotation as XmlSerializer does not need this

```
public class Location
{

}
```

Then

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Location));
const string filePath = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\location.xml";
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
serializer.Serialize(writer, location);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: James, unfortunately, those changes produced no change in behavior. As soon as it tries to instantiate `serializer`, it fails exposing the same error on `AccessorialCharges.`

Comment: Try restarting visual studio/pc this is very strange behavior,

Comment: James, I removed the `[Serializable]` decoration completely, and it still fails the same. Oh, and it's been doing this for two days now...it's survived three restarts and one shut down. Yes, it is very strange...and very pesky, too.

Comment: James, I just threw another restart at my machine and still no change in behavior. Same failure, same place. As soon as I instantiate the serializer, it fails.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` ignores `[Serializable]`.  Doesn't matter if it's there or not.